# Python: csv file operation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Iterate over the second column and return row contents according to its priority, for example, if 'high' is found save it to file, else look for 'intermediate', if found save it to file else look for 'low' if found save it to file and then go for the next item of the column.

csv File:

```
Details,Item Name,Priority,Feature1,Feature2,FeatureN
Details of A,A,High,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of A,A,Intermediate,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of A,A,Low,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of B,B,Intermediate,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of B,B,Low,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of C,C,Low,some feature,some feature,some featureN
```

Expected output:

```
Details,Item Name,Priority,Feature1,Feature2,FeatureN
Details of A,A,High,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of B,B,Intermediate,some feature,some feature,some featureN
Details of C,C,Low,some feature,some feature,some featureN
```

I'm a beginner and reached this far

```
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    import csv


    df = pd.read_csv('29Test.csv')
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

    options = ['Intermediate']


    #selecting rows based on condition
    rslt_df = df[(df['Item Name'] == 'A') &
      df['Priority'].isin(options)]

    rslt_df.to_csv('randomfile.csv', index=False)
```

Now don't know how to make priority conditions and iterate over the second column efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), so possible sorted by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and get first duplicate rows by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('29Test.csv')

df['Priority'] = pd.Categorical(df['Priority'], 
                                ordered=True, 
                                categories=['High','Intermediate','Low'])

rslt_df= df.sort_values(['Item Name','Priority']).drop_duplicates('Item Name')

print (rslt_df)
        Details Item Name      Priority      Feature1      Feature2  \
0  Details of A         A          High  some feature  some feature   
3  Details of B         B  Intermediate  some feature  some feature   
5  Details of C         C           Low  some feature  some feature   

        FeatureN  
0  some featureN  
3  some featureN  
5  some featureN  

rslt_df.to_csv('randomfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It is working perfectly in the way that I wanted.